# Reaching a Backbone.js view from external payment website

Tags: backbone.js

How can I reach the Backbone view from an external third party website or how can I handle real time payment process in a website using Backbone.js?

```
Router.js
route : {
// ....
// Route for callback page
'cart/callback/' : 'retrieveCallbackPage'
}
retrieveCallbackPage : : function () {
            var view = new Backbone.View();
            view = router.appendPage(new CallbackView());
            router.changePage(view);           
        },
```

I have a html file CallBackViewTemplate.html which would be rendered using CallbackView.js

```
// Includes file dependencies
define(["jquery",
            "backbone",
            "text!templates/cart/CallbackViewTemplate.html"],
function ($,
            Backbone,
            CallbackViewTemplate) {
    var CallbackView = Backbone.View.extend({
        // The View Constructor
        initialize: function () {
            this.template = _.template(CallbackViewTemplate);  
        },
    });
```

How can I reach this view by an external third party payment website so that I would get some details from them and save it in my server?

Comment: show some code that you tried

Comment: Updated the question with some code...